# AS3 Will Not let me access classes from other .as files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, package, flash-cs6

I have `MainClass.as` as my document class. Then I created menus. Now I want these menus to be in a different file (package... idk).

This is my new game button from screens.as:

```
    private function newGameButton(Event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var levels:Levels = new Levels();

        stage.focus = stage;
        removeChild(CurrentScreen);
        levels.gotoLevelOne();
    }
```

Here's Levels.as:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Levels extends MovieClip
{
    public var CurrentLevel = "levelOne";

    public function Levels() 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

        trace("working");
    }
    private function onStage(event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
        trace("OnStage");
    }
    public function gotoLevelOne():void
    {
        var levelOne:LevelOne = new LevelOne();

        levelOne.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
        levelOne.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
        addChild(levelOne);

        CurrentLevel = "levelOne";
    }

}
```

}

I've instantiated Levels. My traces work (onStage & working). Yet it still gives me the

> 1009: null object reference. Which object is null?
>
> at Levels/gotoLevelOne()[C:...Flash Files\Levels.as:28]
>
> at Screens/newGameButton()[C:...\Flash Files\Screens.as:38]

so the lines:

```
levelOne.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
```

&

```
levels.gotoLevelOne();
```

Why is levelOne null? Is it not on the display list? I thought it was added to the display list when I instantiated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try debug the movie (ctrl+shift+enter) instead of running it (ctrl+enter), you will have the line and the stack trace when the error occurs and you will see wich var is null.

I think it's stage, while your clip is not on the stage, stage variable is null.

you have to wait for the added to stage event:

```
public function Screens() 
{
    // add the listener to init the menu position
    addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage );
}

private function onStage( event:Event ):void
{
    // remove the event listener
    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, gotoMainMenu );

    // if there is currentScreen place it at the good place
    if( CurrentScreen )
    {
        CurrentScreen .x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
        CurrentScreen .y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
    }
}

public function gotoMainMenu():void
{
    // verify that stage exists so you will never got errors
    if( stage )
    {
        mainmenu.x = stage.stageWidth * .5;
        mainmenu.y = stage.stageHeight * .5;
    }

    addChild(mainmenu);

    mainmenu.newgame_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, newGameButton);
    mainmenu.credits_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, creditsButton);

    CurrentScreen = mainmenu;
}
```

**EDIT**

***so like this you can call gotoMainMenu when you want, this will update the `CurrentScreen` variable and when it is added to stage, the `CurrentScreen` will be placed at the good place***

You can access every public methods and properties of instances after their instanciation.

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MainClass extends MovieClip 
    {
        // declare your property ( don't forget public, private, protected or internal )
        private var menus:Screens;

        public function MainClass() 
        {
            // create your menus
            menus = new Screens();

            // as the Screens object is not on the stage, gotoMainMenu not called so this will trace null here
            trace(menus.CurrentScreen);

            // add it to the display list to be sure to have it initialised
            addChild( menus );

            // now you can get access to preperties
            trace(menus.CurrentScreen);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: \Screens.as, Line 51  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method removeEventListener through a reference with static type flash.events:Event.
 if I remove event. it stops shooting the error, traces "Working" and doesn't show my screen. If I add gotoMainMenu(); under the ADDED_TO_SCREEN listener it expects an argument.

Comment: ah sorry just edit the code as follow: `removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, gotoMainMenu );`

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!!! I didn't know you had to addChild(). It makes sense now. But if I need to call the function 'gotoMainMenu()' what do I put as the argument? (There's a 'back to main menu' button in my credits menu.) Do I need to just right a new function and call that event function ('gotoMainMenu') 'FirstScreenLoad' or something? Kinda confused about arguments.

Comment: ok so maybe you don't want to call this function gotoMainMenu() for the added_to_satge handler but maybe init(), and keep your gotoMainMenu function public and without arguments for calling after

Comment: i will edit the previous answer to show you how to do it

Comment: It's getting a little deeper now. I've got my menus working, my character animated and moving, and a new Level(MC) ready. I want all of my levels to be handled in another file (not Screens file(maybe I should rename Screens.as to Menus.as)) Anyway - I want my newGameButton(in Screens.as) to call the function gotoLevelOne() from my Levels.as file. I'll give my codeby editing my first post.

Comment: nevermind. I feel stupid. didn't addChild(levels); i9n Screens.as... went to sleep and woke up with the answer. Thanks anyways! Do you know of any better ways to handle menus and levels?

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely that you are instantiating MainMenu in the variable declaration. The stage is not defined there yet so it gives you an error in gotoMainMenu. The stage is also not defined in the class constructor function because an object needs to get added to the display list first. Therefore, its best, like stated, to use ADDED_TO_STAGE and instantiate there.

This has other benefits too because you can instantiate objects and not have them do anything until they are added to a display list. Also, instantiating objects in the variable declaration can slow your code down.

To be clear, an object needs to be added to the stage or another object on a display list for stage to NOT be null.

Comment: After I've instantiated 'Screens' how do I use its those functions from 'MainClass'? Everytime I try it says undefined. -Noob